Zooming into Pictures etc. with two fingers on touchscreen
Looking for a solution to zoom a picture etc. similar to the zoom function on smartphone. The center point of the zoom is the mid between finger1 and finger2 the more i pull my fingers apart, the more it should zoom. First i thought that a notebook touchscreen could only record one touch at a time, but Adobe Reader, for example, also supports this two-finger zooming. I’m not entirely sure if implementing something specific would enable the Windows two-finger zoom option, but I don’t find it very appealing, because in my view, it doesn’t zoom in enough considering the finger distance. And therefore it would be cool to write the function for configure it according screen size etc.
import pyautogui
pyautogui.position()

This unfortunately, gives me only back the first finger touch and ignores every further one until the first one is released.
